# Auto expand an NSWindow to fit an NSToolbar using auto layout

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout, nswindow, nstoolbar

I have an NSWindow with an NSToolbar that I present as a sheet. I want the NSWindow to resize to fit the NSToolbar (so the buttons don't get chopped.)

The toolbar is not user configurable, but its size will change due to localisation.

I'm trying to achieve this using auto layout.

Any pointers would be most welcome.

Thanks